# How to change a user's password in Realm data base. iOS App

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, mongodb, realm

Hello everyone who are going to read this.

I’m developing an iOS app that has a registration feature based on the MongoDB’s Realm. Unfortunately they aren’t providing any examples how to handle email confirmation for registration user or changing password. At the moment I'm trying to come up with a way to provide a 'forgot password?' feature.

```
app.emailPasswordAuth.sendResetPasswordEmail(email: email)
```

After calling the code above user will receive a message on provided email. Message contain a link that will be handled by the script I added to the MongoDB Realm app on my RealmUI environment. I put there this script(Some part of this was found on the MongoDB forum, thank you guys).

```
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/realm-web/dist/bundle.iife.js"></script>
<script>
const APP_ID = "app_id";
const app = new Realm.App({ id: APP_ID});
//Grab Tokens
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const token = params.get('token');
const tokenId = params.get('tokenId');

//Confirm client
app.emailPasswordAuth
.callResetPasswordFunction('email@email.com', 'SomethingButNotPassword123', [])
        .then(
    (value) => {
        console.log('SUCCESS');
        displayResult('SUCCESS');
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log(error);
        displayResult('error', err);
    }
);

 app.emailPasswordAuth
 .resetPassword(token, tokenId, 'newPassWord321')
 .then(() => displayResult('success'))
 .catch(err => displayResult('error', err))

//Display Message depending on result
function displayResult(result, err) {
    const message = document.getElementById("message");
    if (result === "success") {
        message.innerText = "Now you can reset your password";
    }
   else if (result === "error") {
       message.innerText = "Unable to change the password for this user. Please try again or contact our support team." + err;
   }
}
</script>

<title>E-mail Confirmation</title>
<style>
    h1 {text-align: center;}
    h3 {text-align: center;}
    h5 {text-align: center; background-color: whitesmoke;}
    p {text-align: center;}
    div {text-align: center;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>App name</h1>
    <h3>Thanks for choosing our app!</h1>
    <h5 id = "message"></h5>
</body>
</html>
```

And this code actually works, it really does change the password for the given email, however It doesn’t fit my needs, because it changes a password for predefined email(new password defined in code as well). I want a user, after confirming that they own email, which was sent from iOS client. Go either to the page on the web with two textfields that are used for filling them with a new version of password, or going direct to the app and type there. I guess universal links could help me to achieve this kind of bahavior(I mean open either web site with textfields or open my app, depends on whether app was installed on the iPhone). I assume that I can put second part of this script to the web somehow and put there those textfields I mentioned above. After user filling them and press button, script executes .resetPasword method. But!

**How can I understand on which email latter was sent by the iOS client from this script?** I mean I need to know email from which the link(`.sendResetPasswordEmail(email: email)` method had sent) was opened

Is this real to perform, or maybe you know another way to handle reset-password feature for realm based application on iOS? Any response would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The question is unclear; *Go either to the page on the web with two textfields that ..., or going direct to the app and type there* - or? How is that decided? What does *How can I understand on which email latter was sent* mean? If they're using the app and go through that process then it was sent from the App, right? But what does that matter - if the password is changed it will ask the user for the password at each logjn, right? Can you clarify the question?

Comment: @Jay
Well, I gave two different scenarios(with text fields on a web site or in the app) because a user can open this email either on their device's mail app or on their computer. In the first case I would use universal links to bring the user back to the app and change the password inside the app. But link can be opened on a computer, so there should be created a possibility to change the password in the browser. 

And no, app won't ask the user for the password at each login. It's actually 'forget password?' feature.

Comment: Ah, I see. Am still not exactly clear on what the issue is though. As you mentioned, *Universal Link*  is generally the solution; it can either direct the user to a website or back to the app. If the app is activated via that universal link, it will know it via the NSUserActivity object. The question states you need to know which email the link was opened from, and I think that's what needs clarity. If you call `sendResetPasswordEmail(email: test@gmail.com...` to an email and then it's opened, wouldn't it have to be opened from the email passed in that parameter?

Comment: @Jay Exactly, it will open from that email. But still, I need to instantiate a variable in the code of the script to paste this email address to another function as a parameter. The function which is responsible for actual reseting password. So I need to know, somehow, inside the script the address of the email. For example as though I got token and tokenID from the url query parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `callResetPasswordFunction()` was redundant, so I refactored(with a help from a friend of mine) my code a little bit and I'm going to post working solution for resetting password.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/realm-web/dist/bundle.iife.js"></script>


    <title>Password resetting</title>
    <style>
        
        h5 { background-color: whitesmoke;}
        {
            text-align: center;
        }
       
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>App name</h1>
<h3>Thanks for choosing our app!</h3>
<h5 id = "message"></h5>

<script>
    const APP_ID = "your app id";
    const app = new Realm.App({ id: APP_ID});
    //Grab Tokens
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const token = params.get("token");
    const tokenId = params.get("tokenId");

    if (!token || !tokenId) {
        alert('Token error')
    } else {
        saveNewPassword('desiredPassword', token, tokenId)
    }


    async function saveNewPassword(newPassword, token, tokenId) {
        console.log('token: ', token)
        console.log('tokenId: ', tokenId)
        console.log('new password: ', newPassword)

        try {
            await app.emailPasswordAuth.resetPassword({
                password: newPassword,
                token,
                tokenId,
            });
            console.log('Password has been changed')
            displayResult('success')
        } catch(err) {
            console.log('Save password error', err);
            displayResult('error')
        }
    }

    //Display Message depending on result
    function displayResult(result, err) {
        const message = document.getElementById("message");
        if (result === "success") {
            message.innerText = "The password has been changed";
        }
        else if (result === "error") {
            message.innerText = "error change password";
        }
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```